# Images won't show after redirect using .htaccess

Tags: image, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am a newbie.. My htaccess now has

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# /viewgallery.php?cname=Colorado-Fall&pcaption=Poked to /photos/Colorado-Fall/Poked.jpg
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+viewgallery\.php\?cname=([^&]+)&pcaption=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /photos/%1/%2.jpg? [R=302,L,NE]
RewriteRule ^photos/([^/]+)/([^.]+)\.jpg$ /viewgallery.php?cname=$1&pcaption=$2 [QSA,L,NC,NE]
```

And redirect works but the images will not show up on my pages if they are not in the root folder. If I have a sub directory created with images(for organizing them), they will create an error as 'images not found'.

Is there a solution for this? Thank you for any suggestions....

Comment: Are you talking about images fetched through the `viewgallery.php` script or the images that are embedded in the page generated by the script (like icons, banners, etc)?

Comment: Jon Lin thank you ... Yes I am talking about icons, banners, thumbnails etc. The images used by the viewgallery.php are in the root folder. but I would like to keep icons, thumbnails , etc in sun folders but that is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a relative/absolute URL thing. Try adding a relative URI base to the header of your page:

```
<base href="/" />
```

Or whatever the correct base should be. Either that, or change all your links to absolute urls:

From:

```
<img src="subfolder/banner.jpg">
```

to:

```
<img src="/subfolder/banner.jpg">
```

Comment: Jon this is something else because I have absolute links on all the images..this is something weird! If I go to the sub-folder and removes the .jpg extension of the image it will show up!  I have no idea why!